# Tracert doesn't return to prompt after "trace complete"?

Tags: windows, traceroute

I am trying to run some tracert via cmd in Windows, but both manually and via a batch script the trace doesn't progress after "trace complete".

In the script it won't move to the next trace and manually it wont return to the prompt.

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! If you try to stop it manually (i.e. with Ctrl-C) does it end?

Comment: Nope. Still hangs at trace complete.

Comment: I've tried running as administrator and also tried a fresh Windows account.

Comment: But the cursor is still there and blinking.. The only way out of it as far as I know is closing the cmd window.

Comment: And you are sure that no icmp/dns-r is going on?

Comment: @bjoster how would I check for that?

Comment: ... wait? (on command line, not in your batch file)

Comment: Either. I'm not sure what you mean by icmp/dns-r..

Comment: I'm not running any other commands other than tracert [ip], hangs after the first trace complete.

Comment: Any more luck in Powershell? I never heard of your problem.

Comment: Will look into powershell, i found this guy having the same issue https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4ea4b9a3-5d35-4d93-b93e-6986c72d1ec4/trace-route-doesnt-close-properly?forum=w8itpronetworking